# Renaming "R" class on build

Tags: android, build

An Android app project is using two library projects as dependencies, Each of the library project has some layout resources and has "R" class auto generated. However, the IDE is getting confused with two inherited "R" classes . Is it possible to change the name of output "R" class by overriding some ANT properties ?

I've already changed dependency order, So IDE looks for main source first and then the library  project but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the name of output "R" class by overriding some ANT properties ?

Not that I am aware of. Simply fully qualify one (or both) of the `R` references (e.g., `com.wingman.libraryone.R`, so you are not relying upon `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using similar namespaces, that might be the problem. I'll try changing namespaces. Also I've noticed that each "R" class generated, is carrying all its ancestor values upon build. Hence I think I need not reference imported ones.

Comment: That worked in code files. But not in layout files when referencing  string resources etc.

Comment: @wingman: All your resources should have unique names, so this should not be an issue. If the resources do *not* have unique names, there's your problem.

Comment: Yes resources have unique names (I'm about to ask a question on this), and now all generated "R" classes have different namespaces. Project compiles and runs perfect. It's just the GUI designer plugin which is unable to display string resources values in preview. Some bug maybe.

Comment: @wingman: Yeah, the Eclipse resolution process for that sort of stuff may not cover all scenarios yet.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. The `R` class is generated by `aapt`, and there is no option on it to use other name.  If you are using resources from different projects in the same file you have to use fully qualified names to resources, like CommonsWare said.